is it possible to call another jenkins file from a main jenkins file
I have a main Jenkins file from which i want to call other jenkinsfiles based on which is chosen. Is is possible to do so ?
I have the main jenkins file which will have a list of choice parameters. Based on what is chosen i want to call the chosen jenkins file.
pipeline {
    agent none

    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'JENKINS_FILE_NAME',
            choices : ['JENKINS_FILE_1', 'JENKINS_FILE_2'],
            description: 'Choose the Application to Deploy'
        )     
    } 

    stages {
        stage('Deploy Application') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'ls -al'
                    
                    switch (JENKINS_FILE_NAME) {
                        case 'JENKINS_FILE_1':
// I want to call jenkins file 1 and execute the stages/steps in this file
                            break
                        case 'JENKINS_FILE_2':
// I want to call jenkins file 2 and execute the stages/steps in this file
                             break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

========================Trial one ------------
@MB i tried this based on your comment. Tried both the load method and build method but the job is unable to find the file in the build method.
ERROR: No item named test-jenkins/Jenkinsfile-B found
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'FUNCTION',
            choices : ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C'],
            description: 'Choose the Application to Deploy'
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('Load and Execute Other Jenkinsfiles') {
            steps {
                script {
                    switch (FUNCTION) {
                        case 'Option A':

                            sh 'ls -al test-jenkins'
                            sh 'ls -al test-jenkins/Jenkinsfile-A'
                            fileA = load 'test-jenkins/Jenkinsfile-A'
                            fileA()
// This fails saying it cannot have pipeline steps                     
                            break
                        case 'Option B':
                            sh 'ls -al'
                            build job: 'test-jenkins/Jenkinsfile-B', parameters: [
                                string(name: 'FUNCTION', value: "${FUNCTION}")
                            ]
                            break
                        default:
                            error "Unknown application: ${FUNCTION}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Each jenkinsfile generally corresponds to a job. What you seem to be looking for is 3 jobs: the one you already have (the triggering job), and 2 for the two jenkins files (the 2 jobs that can get triggered as downstream jobs).
So you just need to create 2 jobs for each of the two jenkinsfiles, then use the  build step to build trigger each job depending on the condition.
If instead you are looking for simple blocks of code to be executed, you can use groovy classes and import them as needed.

I tried based on your comment but it is not able to recognise the file. i added the test code

fileA = load 'test-jenkins/Jenkinsfile-A' you should use the build command as you have done in case B, not load it like this. Also, you should create a new Jenkins job with the jenkinsfile and use the build command on the job. Not the jenkinsfile itself.

i have a master jenkins file with all the options which will call the jenkinsfile-A or B. The load example was just another option i tried . Additionally when i do an ls -l test-jenkins i have the following files
master-Jenkinsfile
Jenkinsfile-A
Jenkinsfile-B

To add to this i think i need to make clear that optionA orB is not anothe JOB but a completely new Jenkins file

Right - what I'm suggesting is that you need to take those file and turn them into Jenkins job.s You shouldn't be trying to load them as files.

You need to modify your sub-jenkinsfiles. They are not full-fledged pipelines that start with pipeline {...} etc. They are more like portions of the calling pipeline. In that sense they behave more like C #include. Here is a minimal example, flesh it out to your needs.
The main jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
  agent { label 'built-in' }
  stages {
    stage('Call sub') {
      steps {
        echo 'Hello from main'
        load 'sub.jenkinsfile'
      }
    }
  }
}

The sub jenkinsfile:
stage('Run sub') {
  echo 'Hello from a sub stage'
}

